# Javascript: Compare Control Flow (to evade anti-debug and anti-tamper traps)

Tags: anti-debugging, javascript, control-flow-graph

When reverse engineering obfuscated javascript, it may be protected by anti-tamper mechanisms.
I have a script which will work when run untouched, but cause a fatal javascript error when run in node after having been beautified.

How can one log the javascript control flow (e.g. when running it via node) to later compare it with a reference to detect where the anti-reverse-engineering mechanisms (anti-debug/anti-tamper) come into effect?